# What network simulation model should I use for simulating the behavior of an ad-hoc network in OMNET++

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I'm working as a student-intern in a govt organization to complete my major-project at college.
My task is to simulate a dynamic-routing protocol for ad-hoc networks. As I've good programming experience in C++ thus I've chosen OMNET++ network simulator. 
It was easy to adapt to the working environment and I could play around with the samples provide in OMNET IDE.

Problem Statement:
Now, I need to start working on my task i.e. [ http://www.mediafire.com/?s5ajo8gavhcf6sr ] pls have a look at the paper.
Could someone please give me a few general instructions on building an adhoc network model in omnet and then apply a routing protocol to it.

I would really appreciate if you could just read the abstract of that paper and provide me deeper insights if possible.

Comment: Or if you could choose a best model from the below given link: http://www.omnetpp.org/models

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your uploaded file is deleted.

So I would suggest to use the INETMANET framework for simulating adhoc network.

There are Manet routing protocols like AODV
You have there Wifi b,g and also 802.15.4 link layers
And there are modules for the whole TCP/IP stack.

Comment: I'm working on creating WSN for omnet++, I'm not sure how to get started with it or using Mixim, could you help me out?